# Byobu status bar conflicts with vim-airline

Tags: vim, tmux, byobu

I started using Byobu and found this interesting problem. 
Then I run Vim with vim-airline plugin (status bar like powerline) inside byobu session, it interferes byobu status bar. The problem exists even if I close vim.

More clearly will be seen on the screenshots:

Vim opened:

[image: Vim opened]

Vim closed:

[image: Vim closed]

Comment: Might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1752).

Comment: @PabloBianchi Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from solution, posted on Github, in the [issue](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1752) mentioned by @PabloBianchi:

> Apparently, to make byobu and powerline correctly display the window
>   names, you will need to add the default command setting to your
>   .tmux.conf (in my case fish):
>
> set-option -g default-command "/usr/bin/fish"
>
> Notably, only the first window will get the name, and the rest will
>   get only a weird hyphen (-) if you create the window using byobu's F2.
>
> However, if you use the standard -c keybinding for the window
>   creation, then all windows will have proper names.